# Composer is messing with github

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I recently used composer to install, via git, a package I created into my project. I then turned my project's `.gitignore` file into one that ignores the `vender/user.name/composer/`
the `vender/user.name/autoload.php` and (I thought, which is causing an issue) the `vender/user.name/PackageName/.git` directory.

With all that ignored I commited the project and came across this on github: [A broken link to a git repository](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/tree/dev1.2/AisisCore/Components/vendor/adam.balan).

1. It should not not be "linking" to another git repository, the last thing I need is this project referencing a git repository, that's why I ignored the `.git/` in this projects `.gitignore` file.
2. This project, on localhost needs to keep the `.git directory so I can do`composer update` when ever I decide to push a new release (essentially dog fooding my own projects). **BUT** I need to be able to commit and download the project (the project in question is linked too in the above link) and see that the folder: **AisisAjax** is **NOT** a reference to a github repo and that it is jus a regular directory of files that i can traverse through.

My [Git ignore file can be seen here ...](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/blob/dev1.2/.gitignore)

Help Please. No matter what I do every time I commit to gihub I see this reference (broken as it may be), while on my local machine I see the files inside of AisisAjax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just doing it completely wrong.

1) You appear to be have a composer.json in a [sub-directory of your project](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/tree/dev1.2/AisisCore/Components). That isn't really supported by Composer.

2) You need to ignore the vendor directory in the .gitignore of the project, which you [don't appear to have](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/blob/dev1.2/.gitignore).

3) Because of 2 and a lack of attention to detail, you've added all the files that Composer downloaded for the component to the main projects Git repository. Composer doesn't add files to a repository so you must have done that yourself.

Pardon me if I'm wrong, but the fundamental problem though is that you appear to not be setting the project name in any of your Composer files and so aren't actually using Composer to install the dependencies, but are doing it yourself.

e.g. The composer file for [Aisis-Framework](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/blob/master/composer.json) should have it's name in it. Then you need to either publish that package on Packagist, or list the URL for it as a repository in the root project composer file to allow it to be installed as a dependency from the root project, rather than doing it yourself.